# Set background image in table view when story boarding is also used

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am doing the following to set the background image:

```
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"appback_new.png"]];
  [self.tableView setBackgroundView:imageView];
```

in view did load method. Also, I made sure that the background color is set to clear color in story board.

But when the view loads, it loads with a black color.

Did any one face this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work :

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appback_new.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = background;
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appback_new.png"]];
```

Comment: First : is it a UIViewController if it is not, make sure that your tableView is connected to it is IBOutlet. In other words check that the tableView in the interfaceBuilder has referencing outlet to tableView.

Comment: I am using story boards and my table view is embedded in navigation controller

Comment: Than the only thing that comes to my mind is that your UITabelViewCell's are custom and has different backgrounds. Make sure that you are using a defaulIdentifier or identifier that corresponds to a cell in the interfaceBuilder and make sure that they have clearColor background or the same background you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

try your code after inserting this line of code

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```